# Perforce CLI - how to determine which changelist a file is checked out under?

Tags: version-control, perforce

In the absence of development branches (or sometimes in the overabundance thereof), it is common to have at least half a dozen of other people's shelves unshelved in a workspace, as well as multiple of one's own: both local changes (divided by directory, of course) and shelves from other workspaces.

(As an aside, yes, this is almost as bad as pre-version control email/tarball/fileshare-based nonsense, and no, there's nothing I can do about it.)

As a result of this situation, it is often necessary to identify which of myriad changelists refers to a given file.

Is there a way of retrieving this information, using the `p4` command line tool, without recourse to elaborate shell scripting or wrapper programmes?

Answer (score 1):

`p4 opened FILE`

Note that this tells you which changelist *you* have the file open in -- it doesn't necessarily correspond to which changelist you may have unshelved from originally.  If this is important, make sure that when you unshelve it's into distinct changelists (rather than opening everything in the same changelist) so you can keep track of what came from where.